# How can I clean up the response for this script to make it more readable?

Tags: python, database, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How can I make the output to for this script into neater format like csv? When I save the response to text it is formatted badly. I tried using writer.writerow but I could not get this method to account for variables.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/ford,2015,f-150,3.5l+v6+turbocharged,3308773,brake+&+wheel+hub,brake+pad,1684"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

meta_tag = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'keywords'})

category = meta_tag['content']

linecodes = []
partnos = []
descriptions = []
infos = []
for tbody in soup.select('tbody[id^="listingcontainer"]'):
    tmp = tbody.find('span', class_='listing-final-manufacturer')
    linecodes.append(tmp.text if tmp else '-')

    tmp = tbody.find('span', class_='listing-final-partnumber as-link-if-js buyers-guide-color')
    partnos.append(tmp.text if tmp else '-')

    tmp = tbody.find('span', class_='span-link-underline-remover')
    descriptions.append(tmp.text if tmp else '-')

    tmp = tbody.find('div', class_='listing-text-row')
    infos.append(tmp.text if tmp else '-')


for row in zip(linecodes,partnos,infos,descriptions):
    result = category + ' | {:<20} | {:<20} | {:<80} | {:<80}'.format(*row)
    with open('complete.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f.write(result + '/n')
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could put it into a pandas dataframe
- Remove the last `for-loop` from the original code.

```py
# imports
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# set pandas display options to display more rows and columns
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 700)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 400)
pd.set_option('display.min_rows', 10)

# your code
url = "https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/ford,2015,f-150,3.5l+v6+turbocharged,3308773,brake+&+wheel+hub,brake+pad,1684"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

meta_tag = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'keywords'})

category = meta_tag['content']

linecodes = []
partnos = []
descriptions = []
infos = []
for tbody in soup.select('tbody[id^="listingcontainer"]'):
    tmp = tbody.find('span', class_='listing-final-manufacturer')
    linecodes.append(tmp.text if tmp else '-')

    tmp = tbody.find('span', class_='listing-final-partnumber as-link-if-js buyers-guide-color')
    partnos.append(tmp.text if tmp else '-')

    tmp = tbody.find('span', class_='span-link-underline-remover')
    descriptions.append(tmp.text if tmp else '-')

    tmp = tbody.find('div', class_='listing-text-row')
    infos.append(tmp.text if tmp else '-')
```

### added code for dataframe

```py
# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(linecodes,partnos,infos,descriptions), columns=['codes', 'parts', 'info', 'desc'])

# add the category column
df['category'] = category

# break the category column into multiple columns if desired
# skip the last 2 columns, because they are empty
df[['cat_desc', 'brand', 'model', 'engine', 'cat_part']] = df.category.str.split(',', expand=True).iloc[:, :-2]

# drop the unneeded category column
df.drop(columns='category', inplace=True)

# save to csv
df.to_csv('complete.txt', index=False)

# display(df)
              codes       parts                            info                                 desc                   cat_desc  brand   model                 engine    cat_part
0           CENTRIC    30016020  Rear; w/ Manual parking brake   Semi-Metallic; w/Shims and Hardware  2015 FORD F-150 Brake Pad   FORD   F-150   3.5L V6 Turbocharged   Brake Pad
1           CENTRIC    30116020  Rear; w/ Manual parking brake         Ceramic; w/Shims and Hardware  2015 FORD F-150 Brake Pad   FORD   F-150   3.5L V6 Turbocharged   Brake Pad
2  DYNAMIC FRICTION  1551160200     Rear; Manual Parking Brake                5000 Advanced; Ceramic  2015 FORD F-150 Brake Pad   FORD   F-150   3.5L V6 Turbocharged   Brake Pad
```